# what does forward slash do in html img tag

Tags: html, css, image

I'm learning html/css and following the tutorial @ W3Schools.com.
The code that I'm having trouble with is @ http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_vertical-align

In line 11

```
<p>An <img src="w3schools_logo.gif" alt="W3Schools" width="270" height="50" /> image with a default alignment.</p>
```

what does the / do just just before the > and after the height attribute?
I looked at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp but it didn't mention /.

Comment: That represent the inline `close` tag.  You would have seen `<p>sdsd</p>` whereas this is just [void tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Comment: @Praveen It was my understanding that the html/css tutorials were fine but the javascript ones contained errors.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely nothing, the trailing `/` is just ignored by the parser.

It is allowed on void tags (i.e. those without other tags/text content inside) by HTML5 specs to make the tag "self-closing", thus the markup valid XML. But it has no HTML-specific meaning.

Conversely, it is compulsory in xHTML for the same reason (making the markup valid XML).

Answer (score 1):

In `HTML` there are two kind of tag :

First, e.g `<div>` that you need to close like `</div>` because it can have other tag inside

Second, e.g `<img/>` `<br/>` that doesn't need `</img> or </br>` to close. These are called void tags means it can't contains other tags.

Answer (score 1):

The **"/"** is basically used for ending tags.
In HTML you need to start your tag and you need to end your tag
the code 
here`<img` 
 marks the opening of the tag
so you need to close it with  `/>`

Answer (score 0):

/> is required for ending HTML tags which don't have a closing tag . They are required to make  tags compliant with XHTML.
Other examples are 
`<br/>`
`<hr/>`

Answer (score 0):

in HTML, elements have a beginning and ending tag e.g. `<p> & </p>` and in between these beginning and ending tags come the content of that element.

But some elements do not have content e.g. `<br />` for line break and `<img src="" />` for images. Such Elements are called empty elements and do not need a closing tag separately. Hence, the `/>` denotes closing of this tag.

Answer (score 0):

in html each end every tag has an opening and closing like for body tag, the syntax is like `<body></body>`

similarly for imagae tag its like `<img></img>`

But we can use the other short form also...which is we are marking the closing option also with the same img tag... `<img/>` and then we can give all the options (properties for the img tag) inside it . `src="w3schools_logo.gif" alt="W3Schools" width="270" height="50"`

so it should be finally like `<img src="w3schools_logo.gif" alt="W3Schools" width="270" height="50" />`